# ComboBox DrawItem event handling for Font Combo Box - WinForms, VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I am creating a combobox which shows fonts in the list, with every font item displayed in its own font style. The combobox loads without errors but the list that shows is all in just one font. I have set `DrawMode = OwnerDrawVariable` and `IntegralHeight = false`, but still no result. The DrawItem code that you can see here is from the MSDN website, with a few changes as per my requirement. Here is my code:

1. `BindCOmboboxes()` is called when the form loads.

   ```
   Private Sub w_BindComboBoxes()   (StyleControl is a User Control containing the combobox)

       'Set Properties

       Dim tFont As Font = Nothing

       StyleControl.TS1Font.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable

       For Each fntfam As FontFamily In FontFamily.Families
           If fntfam.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Regular) Then
               tFont = New Font(fntfam, 12, FontStyle.Regular)
               StyleControl.TS1Font.Items.Add(tFont.Name & ",Regular")               
           End If

           If fntfam.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Italic) Then
               tFont = New Font(fntfam, 12, FontStyle.Italic)
               StyleControl.TS1Font.Items.Add(tFont.Name & ",Italic")
           End If

           If fntfam.IsStyleAvailable(FontStyle.Bold) Then
               tFont = New Font(fntfam, 12, FontStyle.Bold)
               StyleControl.TS1Font.Items.Add(tFont.Name & ",Bold")
           End If
       Next

   End Sub
   ```
2. `DrawItem` function for TS1Font combobox

   ```
   Private Sub FontComboBoxDrawItems(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs)

       Dim size As Integer = 12
       Dim myFont As System.Drawing.Font
       Dim family As FontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial", 12)   <-- to avoid crash
       Dim fntStyle As FontStyle = FontStyle.Regular   <-- To avoid crash
       Dim animalColor As System.Drawing.Color = Color.Black

       Dim str As String = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox).Items(e.Index).ToString.Trim
       Dim brk() As String = str.Split(",")
       For Each fam As FontFamily In FontFamily.Families
           If fam.Name = brk(0) Then family = fam
       Next
       Select Case brk(1)
           Case "Regular"
               fntStyle = FontStyle.Regular
           Case "Bold"
               fntStyle = FontStyle.Bold
           Case "Italic"
               fntStyle = FontStyle.Italic
       End Select

       ' Draw the background of the item.
       e.DrawBackground()

       ' Draw each string in the array, using a different size, color, 
       ' and font for each item.

       myFont = New Font(family, size, fntStyle)
       e.Graphics.DrawString(DirectCast(sender, ComboBox).Items(e.Index).ToString, myFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 
           New PointF(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y))


       ' Draw the focus rectangle if the mouse hovers over an item.
       e.DrawFocusRectangle()

   End Sub
   ```

On debugging in the `DrawItem` function, the values in the statement `e.Graphics.DrawString =` shows proper font family, style and size values. So why doesn't it draw the items that way?

**Result:** 

[image]

Comment: Works on my machine, after fixing the bugs.  Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the source file.

Comment: I did that, but still nothing. Ater I added Option Strict On, it gave me a few errors about data types. I straightened them out, but the result is still the same. :(

Comment: Actually, if I open the combo box and hover over the items really fast, I can see the font style of the hovered item for a fraction of a second and then it goes back to being as shown in the above picture. ??!!